# Rescaling a figure in quarto

Tags: reveal.js, quarto

I'm using quarto to prepare some slides (i.e., *revealjs* output), and I can't find a way to scale an embedded image (e.g., from Wikipedia). It seems the "width" parameters should do but neither a percentage

```
![](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Discharging_capacitor.svg){width="50%"}
```

nor an absolute value

```
![](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Discharging_capacitor.svg){width=600}
```

seems to have any effect on the rendered picture. Any clues?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1:** The easy solution: See [here](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html#stretch) for more information.

> For slides that contain only a single top-level image, the .r-stretch class is automatically applied to the image. You can disable this behavior by setting the auto-stretch: false option

```
format:
  revealjs:
    auto-stretch: false
```

**Option 2:**

If you like that general stretching behavior you can

**A)** deactivate the stretching behavior for an individual slide using

```
## Slide Title {.nostretch}
```

**B)** Create own css class:

The following code uses the same width (30px), but only the one with the own css style works where the trick is the `!important` to overwrite the default set by `.r-stretch` class.

**.qmd**

```
---
format: revealjs
css: styles.css
---

## using css class

![Caption](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Discharging_capacitor.svg){.width-image}


## using inline css does not work

![Caption](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Discharging_capacitor.svg){width=30px}
```

**styles.css**

```
.width-image{
  width: 30px!important;
}
```